# Executing query in MySQL Trigger not working

Tags: mysql

I have two table 'testing1' with fields 'firstname' and 'lastname'. Another table 'testing2' with field 'firstname'.

So the trigger checks first whether the 'NEW.firstname' exists in 'testing2' table or not. If it does then it doesn't execute the INSERT query but if it doesn't exist then the INSERT query is executed and 'NEW.firstname' is added in 'testing2' table.

Here's the trigger that i created ... but I'm getting error in the IF loop ...

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE TRIGGER testRef AFTER INSERT ON testing1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE rowCount INTEGER;
SET @rowCount := ( SELECT COUNT(firstname) FROM testing2 WHERE testing2.firstname =        NEW.firstname );
IF (rowCount) 
INSERT INTO testing2 (firstname) VALUES (NEW.firstname);
END $$
```

I'm unable to figure out where did I made the mistake... Any help ??

Comment: 1- which error? 2- avoid implicit conversions, `rowcount` is an int, not a boolean. 3- don-t you need a `THEN` for your `IF`?

Comment: I fixed the error and now this code which I had pasted below works fine but it doesn't INSERT anything in the second table...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE TRIGGER testRef AFTER INSERT ON testing1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE rowCount INTEGER;
SET @rowCount := ( SELECT COUNT(firstname) FROM testing2 WHERE testing2.firstname =        NEW.firstname );
IF (rowCount) THEN
INSERT INTO testing2 (firstname) VALUES (NEW.firstname);
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But maybe you shoud use IF (rowCount)>0

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER testRef AFTER INSERT ON testing1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE rowCount INTEGER;
SELECT COUNT(firstname) FROM testing2 WHERE testing2.firstname = NEW.firstname INTO rowCount;
IF rowCount = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO testing2 (firstname) VALUES (NEW.firstname);
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```